# Error for ReactJs.Net server side rending with ES6

Tags: reactjs.net

I have been working withe ReactJs.Net and MVC5 application and facing issues with server side rending while using ES6 and babel transpiler. I used expose-loader for exposing the component globally. But it is working only in ES5 syntax . If I use ES6 and Webpack for bundling i am getting the below error in @Html.React() function.

Error while rendering "Hello" to "react_Hq6cd5QfaUu26XrhGgZA": Script threw an exception: Minified React error #130; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?

Code for ~Jsx/Components/Helloworld.jsx

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Helloworld extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>Hello {this.props.name} ,This is my first react component.</div>
        );
          }
}

Code for ~Jsx/server.jsx

import Hello from 'expose?Hello!./components/Helloworld' ;


webpack.config.js

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = 
{
    entry: ['./Jsx/server.jsx'],
    output: { path: './build', filename: 'main.js' },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {
              test: /\.jsx$/,
              loader: ['babel-loader'],
              include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Jsx'),
              query: {
                  presets: ['es2015', 'react']
              }
          },
        ]
       
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
    
    //watch:true
}


RectConfig.cs

 ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
               .SetLoadBabel(false)
               .AddScriptWithoutTransform("~/build/main.js");

The above code works fine if i use the below  ES5 syntax for Helloworld component

var React=require('react');

var Helloworld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
                  <div>
                      Hello {this.props.name} ,This is my first react component.
                  </div>
      );
}
});

module.exports=Helloworld;
```

Please help me if someone knows the solution.

Comment: did you find the solution? facing the same... thanks